# open prettyPhoto onload in fullsize

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, prettyphoto

I have this code to open prettyPhoto in fullsize.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
$.prettyPhoto.open('url','Title','Description');
    });
    </script>
```

How do i do if i want to change the default width and height on prettyPhoto popup.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.prettyPhoto({
  default_width: 500,
  default_height: 344
});
```